# How to change "Add to cart" buttons in Opencart product page

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I use this opencatalog mod for opencart [link here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17504&filter_search=open%20catalog&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=36)

It turns the opencart shopping cart site into a catalog, renames add to cart buttons, changes their functions, etc.

As you can [see here](http://shop.websitedesign.ge/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51)
this mode changes related product add to cart button to "Enquire Now" but the function doesn't changed. This button still works as a add to cart.

But I want to change it to "View More" button with it's function, as I have on home page featured area.

I try to add this code in xml file but it doesn't work for me. When I add this code, both "Enquire Now" buttons on product page changes to "add to cart" again, because both buttons has the same class I think.

```
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/bigshop/template/product/product.tpl">
    <operation error="abort" info="">
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<div class="rating"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[<div class="rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id='.$product['product_id']); ?>" class="button"><?php echo 'View More'; ?></a></div>]]></add>
    </operation>
    </file>
```

Where is my mistake?!
Version of Opencart 1.5.6.4
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text you are showing is from a vqmod file. You need to make sure you have a compatible install of VQMod in your set up. [Link](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/downloads/detail?name=vqmod-2.4.1-opencart.zip&) then make sure the line of code being looked for is actually there in your theme's template files. if not edit the xml file to look for the code from your template it should be in several places eg. featured module and product.tpl
Hope that helps somewhat.